# how child elements are automatically left when child missing one less by use css3 flex

Tags: css, flexbox

The example：

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

li {
  background-color: green;
  flex-basis: 31%;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
</ul>
```

when there are 12 `<li>` tags, page is showing as below:

[image]

when there are 11 `<li>` tags, page will become as shown below:

[image]

however, the result I am looking for is the following:

[image]

so, how can I modify css to achieve this effect
instead of using js?

Comment: Justify your content to `align-left` instead of `space-between`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `justify-content:space-between` you should use `flex-start` to align them left

I have then added the spacing manually (comments in code to what I have changed below)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;        /* change this */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

li {
  background-color: green;
  flex-basis: 31%;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin-left:2%;               /* add this */
  margin-bottom:2%;             /* optional */
}
li:nth-child(3n+1) {            /* this stops the first item on every row having left margin  */
  margin-left:0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achive this you have to set the `justyfy-content` property `flex-start`, so you can have all the elements lined up one after other. And to create the space around effect you have to set the `margin` yourself. In `px` or `%` percentage or `vw` viewport width.

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

li {
  background-color: green;
  flex-basis: 31%;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```